# TypeScript import only as declaration?

Tags: typescript, import, intellisense, declaration, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to import a node module in TypeScript without actually trying to import after compilation?

What I mean:
I created a global variable in a file called intellisense.ts in which I call:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Then in another file referencing it like:

```
/// <reference path="./intellisense.ts" />
fs.existsSync('...');
```

At this point the VSCode intellisense tells me that it cannot find name 'fs'.

Is there a way to work around this without importing fs in the other file?

Please note:

- I need to have fs imported only once
- I don't want to export fs from intellisense.ts
- I don't want to import intellisense.ts in any way
- I DO want to have fs in the global scope only as a reference

Comment: You can't have it all. If you want to use `fs` then you'll need to export it from your `intellisense.ts` and you'll need to import it where you wanna use it. Another option is to have an exported function in `intellisense.ts` which internally will use the imported `fs`. In any case, just referencing the file will work only for compilation but when you'll try to run it you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a global variable in a file

This is not a global variable. It a an imported module in that file. You need to import modules explicitly in each file that uses them.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to be right... It is really sad though, typescript should have a global scope for this kind of stuff. 
Anyways thank you!